# Failure to correctly deduce mixture of Variadic Type and non-Type Template Parameter Packs in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, variadic-templates

Okay folks, I have attempted to minimize the following code to illustrate the problem I am having. It's rather nasty looking, and omits much of the original code. Although not necessarily relevant to the issue I'm having, I'm trying to implement a mechanism for dependency injection. I'm trying to design it such that classes derived from an already injection-dependent class will be able to inherit dependencies from their respective parent. I can provide the full code if desired, but this more minimal version suffices to produce the issue.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ... Dependencies>
class DependencyInjectable
{
public:

    typedef DependencyInjectable<Dependencies ...> tDependencies;
    typedef tDependencies tDependencyInjectable;
    typedef std::tuple<Dependencies ...> tTuple;
    static const constexpr size_t Depth = 0;

    template<typename Arg, typename DecayArg = typename std::decay<Arg>::type, typename ... Args,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<DecayArg, bool>::value>>
    DependencyInjectable(Arg &&arg, Args && ... args) { }

    virtual ~DependencyInjectable(void) { }
};

template<typename T> struct tuple_as_dependency_injectable_type { };
template<typename ... Args> struct tuple_as_dependency_injectable_type<std::tuple<Args ...>>
{
    typedef DependencyInjectable<Args ...> type;
};

template<typename T> struct dependencies_of { typedef T type; };

template<typename Dependency, typename ... Dependencies>
class DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...>
    : virtual public Dependency::tDependencyInjectable,
    public tuple_as_dependency_injectable_type<decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<
                                                        typename Dependency::tDependencyInjectable::tTuple>(),
                                                        std::declval<std::tuple<Dependencies ...>>()))>::type
{
public:

    template<typename Arg, bool = Arg::Depth != 0, typename ... Args>
    struct get_virtual_bases
    {
        typedef typename Arg::tBase T;
        typedef typename get_virtual_bases<T, T::Depth != 0,
            typename Arg::tDependencyInjectable, Args ...>::type type;
    };

    template<typename Arg, typename ... Args>
    struct get_virtual_bases<Arg, false, Args ...>
    {
        typedef std::tuple<typename Arg::tDependencyInjectable, Args ...> type;
    };

    typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename Dependency::tDependencyInjectable::tTuple>(),
                     std::declval<std::tuple<Dependencies ...>>())) tTuple;
    typedef typename tuple_as_dependency_injectable_type<tTuple>::type tDependencies;
    typedef DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...> tDependencyInjectable;
    typedef Dependency tBase;
    static const constexpr auto Depth = 1 + std::tuple_size<typename get_virtual_bases<tBase>::type>::value;

    template<typename Arg, typename ... Args, typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<typename std::decay<Arg>::type, decltype(std::make_index_sequence<Depth - 1>{ })>::value, int>::type = 0>
        DependencyInjectable(Arg &&arg, Args && ... args)
        : DependencyInjectable(std::make_index_sequence<Depth - 1>{ }, std::make_index_sequence<1 + sizeof ... (Args)> { },
                               std::forward_as_tuple(arg, std::forward<Args>(args) ...)) { }

private:

    template<typename ... Args, size_t ... IndicesOne, size_t ... IndicesTwo>
    DependencyInjectable(const std::index_sequence<IndicesOne ...> &, const std::index_sequence<IndicesTwo ...> &,
                         const std::tuple<Args ...> &tuple)
        : std::tuple_element<IndicesOne, typename get_virtual_bases<
        typename Dependency::tDependencyInjectable>::type>::type(std::get<IndicesTwo>(tuple) ...) ...,
        tDependencies(std::get<IndicesTwo>(tuple) ...) { }

public:

    virtual ~DependencyInjectable(void) { }
};
```

Here is a code snippet that tests the class:

```
struct DependencyOne { };
struct DependencyTwo { };

class DependentClassOne
: virtual public DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne *>
{
public:

    DependentClassOne(const tDependencies &dependencies) : tDependencyInjectable(dependencies) { }
    virtual ~DependentClassOne(void) { }
};

class DependentClassTwo
: public DependentClassOne,
  virtual public DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<DependentClassOne>, DependencyTwo *>
{
public:
    DependentClassTwo(const tDependencies &dependencies)
    : tBase(dependencies),
      tBase::DependencyInjectable(dependencies),
      tDependencyInjectable(dependencies) { }

    virtual ~DependentClassTwo(void) { }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DependencyOne dependencyOne;
    DependencyTwo dependencyTwo;

    auto &&tuple = std::make_tuple(&dependencyOne, &dependencyTwo);

    DependentClassOne dependentClassOne(tuple);
    DependentClassTwo dependentClassTwo(tuple);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with GCC 6.3.0 produces the following errors:

```
: In instantiation of 'DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...>::DependencyInjectable(std::index_sequence<IndicesOne ...>&, std::index_
sequence<IndicesTwo ...>&, const std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&) [with Args = {const DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*, DependencyTwo*>&}; long long unsigned int ...IndicesOne = {0ull}; long long unsigned
int ...IndicesTwo = {0ull}; Dependency = DependentClassOne; Dependencies = {DependencyTwo*}; std::index_sequence<IndicesOne ...> = std::integer_sequence<long long unsigned int, 0ull>; std::index_seque
nce<IndicesTwo ...> = std::integer_sequence<long long unsigned int, 0ull>]':
:63:88:   required from 'DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...>::DependencyInjectable(Arg&&, Args&& ...) [with Arg = const Dependency
Injectable<DependencyOne*, DependencyTwo*>&; Args = {}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::decay<Arg>::type, decltype (typename std::_Make_integer_sequence<long long unsigned int, (
DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...>::Depth - 1), typename std::_Build_index_tuple<(DependencyInjectable<dependencies_of<Dependency>, Dependencies ...>::Depth - 1)>::__t
ype>::__type{})>::value), int>::type <anonymous> = 0; Dependency = DependentClassOne; Dependencies = {DependencyTwo*}]'
:99:41:   required from here
:72:54: error: no matching function for call to 'DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*>::DependencyInjectable(bool)'
         tDependencies(std::get<IndicesTwo>(tuple) ...) { }
                                                      ^
:16:5: note: candidate: template<class Arg, class DecayArg, class ... Args, class> DependencyInjectable<Dependencies>::DependencyInjectable(Arg&&, Args&& ...)
     DependencyInjectable(Arg &&arg, Args && ... args) { }
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:16:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
:5:7: note: candidate: constexpr DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*>::DependencyInjectable(const DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*>&)
 class DependencyInjectable
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:5:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'bool' to 'const DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*>&'
```

Specifically, I am puzzled as to why GCC emits this error:

**:72:54: error: no matching function for call to 'DependencyInjectable::DependencyInjectable(bool)'
         tDependencies(std::get(tuple) ...) { }**

Obviously, template argument deduction is failing, but I'm not sure as to why. How is **'bool'** being deduced? GCC seems to struggle with the following line:

```
typename Dependency::tDependencyInjectable>::type>::type(std::get<IndicesTwo>(tuple) ...) ...,
```

I purposely added the following constructor in the base class to trap the issue:

```
template<typename Arg, typename DecayArg = typename std::decay<Arg>::type, typename ... Args,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<DecayArg, bool>::value>>
DependencyInjectable(Arg &&arg, Args && ... args) { }
```

This code is accepted by Microsoft Visual Studio 14 and runs as expected. A slightly different version compiles with Clang, although this particular version may not. Either Clang and Visual Studio are correct or GCC correctly rejects my code. What am I missing?

Comment: Any time I see deduction issues in constructors, I make sure I add explicit keyword to any constructors with (possibly) one argument. Does adding explicit help?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Andrew. I gave that a try, but still no luck. I'm completely puzzled as to why gcc deduces the 'bool'. I have verified this code also compiles with llvm-Clang (but Clang, at least Apple's version, tends to be less compliant to the standard).

Comment: I added explicit to the constructor of DependentClassOne. I now get the compile error: <source>: In constructor 'DependentClassTwo::DependentClassTwo(const tDependencies&)':
<source>:100:47: error: no matching function for call to 'DependentClassOne::DependentClassOne(const tDependencies&)'
       tBase::DependencyInjectable(dependencies). The dependencies for DependentClassOne are different from DependentClassTwo aren't they?

Comment: If you change the constructor of DependentClassTwo to: explicit 
    DependentClassTwo(const tDependencies &dependencies)
    : tDependencyInjectable(dependencies),
      tBase(dependencies),
      tBase::DependencyInjectable(typename DependentClassOne::tDependencies(dependencies))
       { }     Then you get the compile error note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const tDependencies {aka const DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*, DependencyTwo*>}' to 'const tDependencies& {aka const DependencyInjectable<DependencyOne*>&}' as expected. I am confused why this works in clang.

Comment: Adding explicit to DependencyInjectible constructor causes clang to no longer compile. In short, I am guessing this works in clang and vs due to implicit conversions.

Comment: Thanks for taking another look at it. I applied the explicit directive to just the constructors in the specialization. I actually did intend for the implicit conversion in the un-specialized version to take place - the reason why is that I want classes that derive from an already injection dependent class to inherit the base class's dependencies - it's hard to tell what my intent is from this condensed version. In this case, DependentClassOne will be initialized with more dependencies than it needs, but it just ignores those which it doesn't need. I can post the full code, but it's kinda long.